# MySQL Workbench Visualising techniques

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I wonder if there is a better way to visualize table using mysql workbench for a single entity along with its related tables. Is there a better way to visualize table in a diagram instead of table definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Reverse Engineer** option on Modeling context of Workbench. Here is it how:

1. On Workbench, go to `File` > `New Model`
2. On the new Model window, choose `Database` > `Reverse Engineer`
3. Follow the wizard to connect to the schema and Workbench will get you the Model Diagram

Answer (score 1):

Hello_

You can make **EER Diagrams** with **MySQL Workbench**.

Refer to the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-creating-eer-diagram.html), watch video in youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAf-3LWDpOo), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bk0n2QLLxPI) or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yq9iCb2JRHk) or even search [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql%20workbench%20making%20eer%20diagram%20tutorial&*)

You can start making such a diagram from **home** screen - for new database or from existing one.

Cheers!